# Center align* within gather*

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, gather

Running the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{gather}
    \sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}\\
    \begin{align}
        \cos{2x}&=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}\\ 
                &=1-2\sin^2{x}\\
                &=2\cos^2{x}-1
    \end{align}
\end{gather}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

generates this:

[image]

I would like to create the text as above but without equation numbers.

Using `gather*` and `align*` in the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
    \sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}\\
    \begin{align*}
    \cos{2x}&=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}\\ 
                &=1-2\sin^2{x}\\
                &=2\cos^2{x}-1
    \end{align*}
\end{gather*}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

generates this:

[image]

Why does the lack of equation numbers cause the aligned portion of the text to no longer be centered, and how can it be centered?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{align}
\sin{2x}&=2\sin{x}\cos{x}\\
\cos{2x}&=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}\notag\\
&=1-2\sin^2{x}\notag\\
&=2\cos^2{x}-1
\end{align}
\hrule
\end{document}`?

Comment: That's close to what I was trying to do, except for the equation numbers on the first and fourth line. In addition to the other two lines, adding `\notag` to the second and third removes the equation numbers. However, the equal sign of the first line is aligned with the other three, and I wanted to see if there was a way to center the first line instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had not nested `align*` inside any math environment. For such cases is defined in the `amsmath` package `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
    \sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}\\
    \begin{aligned} % <------------
    \cos{2x}&=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}\\
                &=1-2\sin^2{x}\\
                &=2\cos^2{x}-1
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\hrule

\medskip
but, what you not use simple the following :

\medskip
\hrule
\begin{align*}
    \sin{2x} & = 2\sin{x}\cos{x}\\
    \cos{2x} & =  \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}\\
             & = 1-2\sin^2{x}\\
             & = 2\cos^2{x}-1
    \end{align*}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I chose not to align the equal signs of the first and second identities because the two are not equal, and I thought that aligning the equal signs implies that they are.

Comment: @AndrewFK,  how you like to write your equation,  is up to you. However, the first example solves your problem, doesn't it?